# path is being added to filename using nodejs fs module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a file and save to `path` with below code its creating file into records directory but filename is coming as `./app/records/server2b22f465-f7c9-4131-b462-93bc19760ab1.txt` path is included in file name , what i am missing so i can only save filename without the path into records folder ?

main.js

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = './app/records'

var userLogs = function (data) {
    var filename = 'server' + uuid.v4() + '.txt';
    var file = path + '/' + filename;
    fs.writeFile(file,data,function () {
        console.log(file);
    });
    console.log('userLogs', data);
};
module.exports = userLogs;
```

Comment: `fs.writeFile` resolves the path relative to the working directory. Since you don't provide any information about your file structure / environment, it's difficult to give any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I believe that the path you pass to `fs.writeFile` needs to be absolute.</strike> You can use node's native path module to resolve a relative path to an absolute path. The method to do so is `path.resolve()`.

So try this:

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var filePath = path.resolve('./app/records');

var userLogs = function (data) {
    var filename = 'server' + uuid.v4() + '.txt';
    var file = filePath + '/' + filename;
    fs.writeFile(file,data,function () {
        console.log(file);
    });
    console.log('userLogs', data);
};
module.exports = userLogs;
```

Edit: `fs.writeFile` does not need an absolute path

According to the Node fs docs:

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system

> The relative path to a filename can be used. Remember, however, that this path will be relative to `process.cwd()`

Comment: The path you pass to `fs.writeFile()` does not need to be absolute.  If it's not absolute, then it will be resolved relative to the current working directory.